# Facebook Key Hash for Play Store Release

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-3.0

I have created a hash key for my android app which is using Facebook SDK. However, now I want to create the hash key for 'release' version of my app. For that I am using a different keystore.

I have the following syntax :

`keytool -exportcert -alias MY_ALIAS_HERE -keystore ~/path/to/my/android.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`

Here, `MY_ALIAS_HERE` is the alias present in that keystore file? Or something other? Also, the password is 'android' or something else like the password for that alias in keystore file?

Thanks a lot.. :)

Comment: ARe you giving a alias name whenever you are exporting the app??

Answer (score 2):

mdDroid answer is correct. You just missed to give the path of your openssl. if you don't find openssl.exe file in your C: drive, just download openssl from [here](https://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/). Then replace "openssl" with the path of openssl.exe file like

`C:\bin\openssl`

i install openssl in C: drive thats why this is the path of my openssl, your openssl path should be the path of openssl.exe files location. Now try the ans of @mdDroid. you should get your key hash. Happy coding  ...... :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace my path and alias to your,

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin\keytool.exe" -exportcert -alias manoj -keystore c:\users\manoj\desktop\manoj.kp | C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl base64
```

Comment: yes but the alias manoj is there in manoj.kp keystore? and also the password it will ask is same as that of that alias in keystore?

Comment: you should give the path of your signing keystore and password should be the password which you r using for generating apk.

Comment: I did the same thing, my alias in keystore file is `shaarad` and suppose password is `pass` then I used `keytool -exportcert -alias shaarad -keystore C:\Users\shaarad\keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64` and entered. When asked for password I entered pass.  I copy pasted the hash to app dashboard and saved. Still it's not working.